# Pockets of what looks like dirt behind shower walls

Tags: shower, tile, demolition

So after frustration of fighting off ants multiple times over the past years, and starting to see what appears to be fungus gnat in the bathroom recently, I started to demo my bathroom shower. As I got closer to the drainpan at the bottom of the shower, after I removed tiles I started to see these pockets of what looks like dirt behind them. After I reach the floor, in the wall, there was damp dirt surrounding the drainpan. After I looked closer at the back of the tiles I noticed these bugs crawling around. Any help would be appreciative.

[image]

Comment: I'm not an entomologist but the bugs look like termites.

Comment: I agree, they dont look like ants.  Perhaps its time to call a pest controller that can handle termites.